# replace form id with new id?

Tags: jquery

How to replace form tag id with new id?

```
  <form method="post" action="contactus.aspx" id="ctl01">
```

replace `id="ctl01"` with `id="validForm"`

### Update

look like `ctl01` id generating by code. by the time we changing id name, 'crl01` is not available yet. How to handle after page loaded?

Comment: Change the attribute value with .attr. http://learn.jquery.com | http://try.jquery.com

Comment: Open up your favorite HTML editor, delete `ct101` using the backspace key, type in `validForm` instead, save! Everybody happy happy?

Answer (score 4):

Get the element in Javascript and change it.

```
document.getElementById('ctl01').id = 'validForm';
```

You can also use `jQuery.attr();`.

```
$('#ctl01').attr('id','validForm');
```

To wait for the DOM to load, use this:

```
$(document).ready({
  //DOM is ready
});
```

A common syntax is also this:

```
$(function() {
  //DOM is ready
});
```

There are also other ways, but these are the most common.

Comment: look like ctl01 id generating by code. by the time we changing id it is not available yet. How to handle after page loaded?